# Why is std::underlying_type<T> unsigned when T is not?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, unsigned-integer

Consider this trivial code:

```
int main() {
  enum Simple { one = 1, two = 2 };
  Simple m1 = static_cast<Simple>(-1);
  if (m1 < 0) return -1;
  return 1;
}
```

Not surprisingly, this returns -1.

What is surprising, is that when I used std::underlying_type<Simple>, the underlying type is "unsigned int".  wtf?  If the underlying type of Simple is unsigned, how did it get to be less than zero?

Further evidence:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  enum Simple { one = 1, two = 2 };
  Simple m1 = static_cast<Simple>(-1);

  std::underlying_type<Simple>::type underlying = m1;

  long long llm1 = m1;

  std::cout << "simple=" << m1
            << " underlying=" << underlying
            << " long long=" << llm1
            << "\n";
}
```

Produces:

simple=-1 underlying=4294967295 long long=4294967295

Comment: A combination of implicit conversions and integral promotions, I'd wager.

Comment: How can code that doesn't even compile, produce output?

Comment: The underlying type for enums without `class` or an explicit underlying type is *implementation-defined*  except that it is not allowed to be a type larger than `int` unless the enumerators cannot fit in `int`.  Your first example shows that (prior to C++17!) your compiler used a signed type as the underlying type.   If `std::underlying_type<Simple>` actually resolved to `unsigned int`, then the combination of those two cases would indicate a compiler bug.  However you should post some evidence that `std::underlying_type<Simple>` is actually `unsigned int` according to your claim

Comment: M.M first comment: The code does compile and does produce output.

Comment: M.M second comment: My proof is to look at the generated code, see http://goo.gl/luxzJ1 .  The first call to output m1 calls basic_ostream::operator<<(int), while the second one calls basic_ostream::_M_insert<unsigned long> and the third one calls basic_ostream::_M_insert<long long>.  So for some reason, when calling cout << enum, the compiler thinks it's just fine to consider the enum to be an int, but then later it thinks the underlying type is an unsigned long, and does something entirely different.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the documentation for [`static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast)

> 8) Integer, floating-point, or enumeration type can be converted to any complete enumeration type. The result is **unspecified** (until C++17) **undefined** behavior (since C++17) if the value of expression, converted to the enumeration's underlying type, is out of range (if the underlying type is fixed, the range is the range of the type. If the underlying type is not fixed, the range is all values possible for the smallest bit field large enough to hold all enumerators of the target enumeration)

Comment: The definition of "range" there semes a bit unclear for non-fixed enums (which this one is), but `-1` would be in range for any signed bitfield

Comment: @m.m.  an unsigned bit field of 2 bits is enough to store 1 and 2.  A signed bit field of 2 bytes is not.  In general, for an enumeration with all positive enumerators, an unsigned bit field is going to be 1 bit smaller than the signed bit field required; thus the smallest bit field required is unique, and always unsigned if the enumerators are all positive.

Comment: In other news, I'm heartened to see that `static_cast<Simple>(-1)` can cause the hard drive to be formatted in C++17. How long before we see the first case of a compiler removing big chunks of a function because it had a code path leading to that?

Comment: @Yakk OK, I see that C++14 has a formal definition . I guess the quoted text here is paraphrasing a similar formal definition in C++17 draft.

Comment: @m.m. Well, it makes code golfing easy.  Simply cause UB and provide a compiler that does whatever you need in that particular case.

Comment: If the enumeration were started at zero, two bits could also store -1 (two's complement and sign magnitude) , but still only one bit would be needed to store that range.

Comment: I guess with an enum containing only zero, either an unsigned or signed 1 bit field can be the underlying storage (signed can store `0` and `-1`).  If you have `0`, `1`, `2`, it takes 2 bits to store it as unsigned, and 3 as signed.  I *think* after the enum containing only zero signed always takes an extra bit?

Comment: @Yakk In general, I think you're right.  It would always seem to take at least an extra bit *except* two's complement and the range `-1..0`.

Comment: But http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum says that the simple enum declaration I used "Declares an unscoped enumeration type whose underlying type is not fixed (in this case, the underlying type is either int or, if not all enumerator values can be represented as int, an implementation-defined larger integral type that can represent all enumerator values. If the enumerator-list is empty, the underlying type is as if the enumeration had a single enumerator with value 0)."  So if the underlying type defaults to int, why does std::underlying_type<>::type come back unsigned?

Comment: @jorgbrown As I understand it, the important part is the `static_cast`.  The value `-1` isn't representable using the minimal size bit field representing `1` and `2` (enum range), in which case you're either invoking *unspecified* behavior or *undefined* behavior.  I don't know what `std::underlying_type` is required to return for an `enum`.  If it's required to return the exact type, there may be a compiler or library bug, but output would still depend on *unspecified* or *undefined* behavior.  Though, I suspect `std::underlying_type` isn't required to return the *underlying* type.

Comment: @jorgbrown I think the point is casting values out of range for an `enum` is asking your compiler to steal your girlfriend, crash on your couch, and/or leave empty milk cartons in your refrigerator.